# Conditional axis in vega-lite

Tags: vega-lite

I want to represent two rows in the axis of a graph. The two rows represent month and year respectively.[image]

For the above plot , we use a conditional statement to display year only if the current month is jan, but this logic works well in this plot. But this fails if the plot is rendering only say, Feb, Apr, Jun etc, then the year will not be displayed at all.
I wanted a generic solution to display year only on the first valid occurance be it Jan or Feb etc.

The above can be found in [vegalite editor](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/line_conditional_axis.html)

Comment: Is this for Deneb or just straight VL?

Comment: Its in vega-lite directly

Comment: Davide, I was thinking one possibility would be to add 1000 to the epoch number to the first number and if January. Then check for 1 second in a labelExpression ? 

Comment: The way I would do this is to create a window transform with row_number so you know the first month of each year available (in case it is not Jan) and then put this in an array with the date and then finally check the array and split in the label expression.

Comment: @DavideBacci could you show us an example? That sounds like an interesting solution.

Comment: On thinking about it, I think I prefer the solutions you have come up with as they're a lot less calculation intensive. Good work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had no luck with Temporal labelExpr using H (hour), M (minutes) etc
In this example I set the date to either 1 or 2 and use that logic in the labelExpr.

Let me know if this could be a possible solution for you. I have added lots of dynamic features to show that in action too.

Also added a trick I like to use so tooltip works everywhere. I set the chart to Area instead of line..

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Line chart with conditional axis ticks, labels, and grid.",
  "data": {"url": "data/stocks.csv"},
  "transform": [
    {"filter": "datum.symbol==='GOOG'"},
    {"filter": {"field": "date", "timeUnit": "year", "range": [2006, 2007]}},
    {
      "filter": {
        "field": "date",
        "timeUnit": "yearmonthdate",
        "gte": "2006-03-01"
      }
    },
    {"calculate": "timeFormat(datum.date, '%y%m')", "as": "YM"},
    {"calculate": "timeFormat(datum.date, '%m')", "as": "M"},
    {
      "joinaggregate": [{"op": "min", "field": "date", "as": "firstDate"}],
      "groupby": ["symbol"]
    },
    {
      "calculate": "datetime(timeFormat(datum.firstDate, '%y%m') == datum.YM || datum.M == '01' ? timeFormat(datum.date, '%Y-%m-' + '01') : timeFormat(datum.date, '%Y-%m-' + '02'))",
      "as": "formattedDate"
    }
  ],
  "width": 700,
  "mark": {
    "type": "area",
    "color": "transparent",
    "line": {"color": "#0564C8"}
  },
  "encoding": {
    "tooltip": {
      "field": "formattedDate",
      "type": "temporal",
      "timeUnit": "utcyearmonth"
    },
    "x": {
      "field": "formattedDate",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "timeUnit": "utcyearmonthdate",
      "bandPosition": 0,
      "axis": {
        "title": "",
        "tickCount": 12,
        "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
        "labelAlign": "left",
        "labelExpr": "[timeFormat(datum.value, '%b'), timeFormat(datum.value, '%d') == '01' ? timeFormat(datum.value, '%Y') : '']",
        "labelOffset": 4,
        "grid": true,
        "labelPadding": {
          "expr": "timeFormat(datum.value, '%d') == '01' ? -26:-11"
        },
        "tickSize": {"expr": "timeFormat(datum.value, '%d') == '01' ? 30:15"},
        "gridDash": {
          "expr": "timeFormat(datum.value, '%d') == '01' ? []:[2,2]"
        },
        "tickDash": {
          "expr": "timeFormat(datum.value, '%d') == '01' ? []:[2,2]"
        },
        "tickColor": {
          "expr": "timeFormat(datum.value, '%d') == '01' ? '#0564C8':'silver'"
        },
        "gridColor": {
          "expr": "timeFormat(datum.value, '%d') == '01' ? '#0564C8':'silver'"
        }
      }
    },
    "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative", "axis": {"grid": false}}
  },
  "config": {"axis": {"domainColor": "#ddd", "tickColor": "#ddd"}}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is another alternative using additional Text marks. With this setup you have a bit more control of the layout:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Line chart with conditional axis ticks, labels, and grid.",
  "data": {"url": "data/stocks.csv"},
  "transform": [
    {"filter": "datum.symbol==='GOOG'"},
    {"filter": {"field": "date", "timeUnit": "year", "range": [2006, 2007]}},
    {
      "filter": {
        "field": "date",
        "timeUnit": "yearmonthdate",
        "gte": "2006-03-01"
      }
    },
    {
      "joinaggregate": [{"op": "min", "field": "date", "as": "firstDate"}],
      "groupby": []
    }
  ],
  "width": 500,
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "area",
        "color": "aliceblue",
        "line": {"color": "#0564C8"}
      },
      "encoding": {
        "tooltip": [
          {
            "field": "date",
            "type": "temporal",
            "timeUnit": "utcyearmonth",
            "title": "Date"
          },
          {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative", "title": "Price"}
        ],
        "x": {
          "field": "date",
          "type": "temporal",
          "axis": {
            "title": "",
            "tickCount": 10,
            "labelAlign": "left",
            "labelExpr": "timeFormat(datum.value, '%b')",
            "labelOffset": 4,
            "labelFont": "Arial",
            "labelFontSize": 10,
            "labelPadding": -24,
            "tickSize": 30,
            "grid": false,
            "gridDash": {
              "condition": {
                "test": {"field": "value", "timeUnit": "month", "equal": 1},
                "value": []
              },
              "value": [2, 2]
            },
            "tickDash": {
              "condition": {
                "test": {"field": "value", "timeUnit": "month", "equal": 1},
                "value": []
              },
              "value": [2, 2]
            }
          }
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "price",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {"grid": false, "title": ""}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [
        {"filter": "datum.date == datum.firstDate"},
        {"calculate": "timeFormat(datum.date, '%Y')", "as": "dateYear"},
        {"calculate": "0", "as": "dateVal"}
      ],
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "align": "left",
        "baseline": "top",
        "dx": 5,
        "dy": 20,
        "font": "Arial",
        "fontSize": 10,
        "color": "#0564C8"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "dateYear", "type": "nominal"},
        "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
        "y": {"field": "dateVal", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [
        {"filter": "datum.date !== datum.firstDate"},
        {"filter": "timeFormat(datum.date, '%m') == '01'"},
        {"calculate": "timeFormat(datum.date, '%Y')", "as": "dateYear"},
        {"calculate": "0", "as": "dateVal"}
      ],
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "align": "left",
        "baseline": "top",
        "dx": 5,
        "dy": 20,
        "font": "Arial",
        "fontSize": 10,
        "color": "#0564C8"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "dateYear", "type": "nominal"},
        "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
        "y": {"field": "dateVal", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {"axis": {"domainColor": "#ddd", "tickColor": "#ddd"}}
}
```

[image]